# Prove that $\langle S \rangle = G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $S\subset G$ be a finite group such that $\#2S\gt\#G$

Prove that $\langle S \rangle = G$

My idea was to start by taking $a \in G$ and proving that $ax^{-1}$ is also in $G$ if $x$ is in $S$, but I don't know how to use the assumption.

Comment: Why are you writing $\langle\langle S \rangle\rangle$ rather than just $\langle S \rangle$?

Comment: @DerekHolt The OP might be referring to the normal closure of $S$ instead of the subgroup generated by $S$.

Comment: Actually, $<S>=G$ obvious. But in that case we can say more, $S.S=G$.

Answer (score 2):

$2 \#S > \#G$ shows $(G:\langle S \rangle)<2$, hence the result.

Comment: S is merely a subset so how do I know that Lagrange works?

Comment: But $\langle S \rangle$ is a subgroup that contains $S$.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Thanks!